# codecademy python excercise 5.Pull it Together - how to sum trip_cost()

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have no idea how to sum arguments in the last function: trip_cost()
Instead of what I've typed i get an error says:

"Oops, try again. trip_cost('Los Angeles', 6) raised an error: global name 'plain_ride_cost' is not defined"

(And each time I point "Save and Submmit" to check, it gives me in parentheses a different name city from the list and another number after a comma in the error note.)

but i have tried some different ways till now and it doesn't work for me.
Can anyone help me go through this one?:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
    else:
        print("unkown costs")

def rental_car_cost(days): 
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 3 and days <7: 
        cost -= 20
        return cost
        print cost
    elif days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
        return cost
    else:
        return cost

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return hotel_cost(days) + plain_ride_cost("Los Angeles") + rental_car_cost(days)
```

Comment: `plain_ride_cost != plane_ride_cost `

Answer (score 0):

You have named your function wrong.

You called it plain_ride_cost("Lost Angeles") in your trip_cost() return.

However it should be plane_ride_cost()

Change the last method to this.

```
def trip_cost(city, days):
return hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost("Los Angeles") + rental_car_cost(days)
```